# 3 horizontal collapsible panel divs responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, panel, collapsibletree-r

how to make a bootstrap responsive collapsible horizontal panels  like on the image below?

Will be really thankful if someone could show me how to acheive it.

[image]

Thanks alot, really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
select {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e7ebee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row row-cols-3">
    <div class="col flex-column">
      <select>
        <option selected>Select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option selected>Select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col flex-column">
      <select>
        <option selected>Select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option selected>Select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col flex-column">
      <select>
        <option selected>Select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
      <select>
        <option selected>Select menu</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but the above image is not selection drop down its a collapsible panel which expands and collapses on click

Comment: Actually, it is, but with a bunch of JS converting the options to a collapsible panel. Quickest option is to find a third party, bootstrap compatible "addon" that gives you that look and feel.